# Read file into dataframe spliting the text after the first word in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file of strings `file.txt`, where the first word is a class name and the rest is a description, like the following:

```
n01440764 tench, Tinca tinca
n01443537 goldfish, Carassius auratus
n01484850 great white shark, white shark, man-eater, man-eating shark, Carcharodon carcharias
```

I would like to read the file into a dataframe of two columns `df['class']` with the class and `df['description']` with the rest of the content.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried already?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga so far  `df = pd.read_table(filepath_or_buffer=filename,header=None) 
df_expanded= df.ix[:,0].str.split(' ', expand=True)
df['class'] = df_expanded.ix[:,0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='\s{2,}', engine='python', names=['col'])

df['class'] = df['col'].str.split().apply(lambda x: x[0])
# Splitting on first occurence of whitespace
df['description'] = df['col'].str.join('').apply(lambda x: x.split(' ',1)[1])
del(df['col'])

print (df)

       class                                        description
0  n01440764                                 tench, Tinca tinca
1  n01443537                        goldfish, Carassius auratus
2  n01484850  great white shark, white shark, man-eater, man...
```